Buffer creates "hole" in curving transect
I've got a problem in QGIS I can't seem to solve on my own.
I want to create a buffer polygon along a curving line but when I choose a wider buffer distance my buffer "goes over it self", because of my curving line, and creates a hole. This line is in fact a trasect and I need to calculate my suveyed area so I need to include this hole in the polygon.
One requirement I have is that I am creating many buffers at the same time and many of them goes over each other, meaning that the dissolve function will not work as I need all my individual buffers.
Both the green and the brown polygon are created using the "Buffer" function in QGIS, with the difference that the green one has a much larger buffer distance (and a flat end cap).
Are there any parameter in the buffer function I am missing, or can I solve my problem using any other function?
WKT:
MultiLineString ((264795.02940000034868717 7602947.76929999887943268, 264570.48400000017136335 7602921.15650000050663948, 264412.83389999996870756 7602947.72670000046491623, 264354.32039999961853027 7602949.85449999943375587, 264315.40969999972730875 7602951.26940000057220459, 264287.10749999992549419 7602929.80449999868869781, 264289.83139999955892563 7602895.93250000104308128, 264330.64329999964684248 7602833.58100000023841858, 264356.71760000009089708 7602767.82849999889731407, 264363.51960000023245811 7602715.67999999970197678, 264335.1780000003054738 7602680.53640000149607658, 264293.23240000009536743 7602658.99680000171065331, 264246.75219999998807907 7602646.52650000154972076, 264211.60869999974966049 7602693.00670000165700912, 264184.78990000020712614 7602735.77169999852776527))

can you tell us some more about how you created the green polygon, since the brown polygon looks as I would expect

Could you share the data?

The green polygon is created in the same way as the brown (but with a flat end cap) but with a larger buffer distance. They both are created using the Buffer funtion. So my problem appears with large buffer distances.

The line is made up of multiple lines? Try dissolving it then buffer

I recommend dissolving, but using some other end cap style than flat might help a bit.

but can you tell/show us the actual parameters you used

Please copy the linestring geometry as WKT. I tried to draw something similar but I didn't manage to get such a hole.

WKT for the line added above!

Using round or square end cap result in no hole so it seem the problem is caused by the way the flat end cap are crated...

I belive the problem is embedded in the way the flat end cap works. See figure 7, 12: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/381034985_The_Challenges_of_Line_Buffers_Issues_and_Methods/figures?lo=1. Are there a work around? I tired the square- and round end cap I notice that the hole disappears with these parameters. But these two end cap styles will make it difficult for me to calculate the true size of the surveyed area, as it has the shape using the flat end cap

You cant try a larger number for segments per quadrant. Something like 16 instead of 5.
